# Programming error Buick Enclave 2008

Tags: buick, electronic-control-module, flash-programing, enclave

I just installed a brand new PCM on my Buick enclave 2008 gives me the P0602 code, the vehicle does not work, and some tell me it takes flasher PCM? I would like to know how flacher PCM (the stage) and is what a poor fitting of the box can cause this code "programming error."

Answer (score 2):

P0602 simply means the control module is not programmed.

Programming is generally required when installing a new PCM in most modern vehicles.

You will need to take the vehicle and the new PCM to a shop with the specialize equipment to program the computer.

There really isn't a DIY solution to this problem.

Comment: It should be noted that PCM/ECM's are shared between models of cars which utilize the same basic engine. This allows for design efficiencies and cost savings. When they send you a PCM for the Enclave, it could also possibly work in a Traverse or Cadillac or what have you. Each one will have a different tune specific to the vehicle itself. This is why it is sent without a tune already installed.